# jquery datatables Callbacks : fnStateLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

[fnStateLoad](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks)  like this,

```
  $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
          var o;

          // Send an Ajax request to the server to get the data. Note that
          // this is a synchronous request.
          $.ajax( {
            "url": "/state_load",
            "async": false,
            "dataType": "json",
            "success": function (json) {
              o = json;
            }
          } );

          return o;
        }
      } );
    } );
```

I want load progress bar while come back to server response with jquery datatables. progress bar must be load 100% when success response. can i modify this code for load progress bar and how to do ? I'm not sure `fnStateLoad` can use for do this.(**real-time calculate for server response**)